# Define Width, Height, Length in Different Orientation 3D Space?

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

I would like to ask this simple question. How we can define the W, H, and L of the object with different orientations? I mean for example in object 1, the W can be Xmax-Xmin, but it wouldn't work for object 2 (Ymax-Ymin). Any clues? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: How are you going to use width, height and length?

Comment: @MBo, I have numbers of objects in my data, then I want to filter it out by some criteria using WHL. Is it possible or to use such criteria?

Comment: You can store WHL for every object in some standart orientation and use when needed. If you really need coordinate difference for every axis - calculate these differences "on the fly" - note that for example, for rotated by 45 degrees (if this case is important) coordinate differences are not equal to any of initial dimensions

Comment: @MBo that's right actually. Not as simple as that. It just based on my visual where the data are in a normal position without any rotation. That's why I try to use the WHL criteria to filter it. Really thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Perhaps you want `Bounding box`

Comment: Yes right, I also think about that. Thank you @MBo